# Trying to use JBDC but getting error finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, gradle, mysql-connector

I'm trying to implement a simple use of JBDC for studying purposes, but iḿ getting error "finished with non-zero exit value 1". Below is my code and the gradle.build.

My code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionJBDC {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        String urlConnection = "jbdc:mysql://localhost/digital_innovation_one";
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlConnection , "MyLogin" , "MyPass");
            System.out.println("Sucesso");
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Falhou");
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My gradle.build:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'one.innovation.digital'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.26'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The error i get when i try to run the program:

```
Execution failed for task ':ConnectionJBDC.main()'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Can someone help ? I'm clueless (just a noob here).

Comment: `Run with --stacktrace` as the error clearly states. But

Comment: *`System.out.println("Falhou");`* is not going to help you.You want `e.printStacktrace();`

Comment: use `jdbc: ` instead of 'jbdc:mysql'. Check your url

Comment: Thanks guys! Thats my first contact with JAVA, so i don't get everything right. Next time i will use the --stacktrace and e.printStacktrace() (just learned how to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly (maybe not needed according to your driver version), load your driver with this code at the beginning :

```java
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    // this class name change according to your driver. In your case, I think it's good one
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // Cannot find driver for MySQL
}
```

Then you don't set the good driver name. Use this one:

`jdbc:mysql://localhost/digital_innovation_one`

(jdbc instead of jbdc)